# What is the advantage of using structs for UOMs like Temperature?

Tags: c#, performance, testing, struct, temperature

I ran the code below to test speed of some common uses in my program for UOM's and was quite surprised.  With the results:  All tests were run 1 million times in debug mode (run mode gave similar differences).  It seems there is no real advantage in using structs for UOMs from a speed point of view so can anyone tell what any advantages would be? (I have a big number crunching program and this is of huge interest to me).  If the example code is wrong in any way below, please let me know also.  What I really want is the most convenient way to handle UOMs without making the code verbose (UOM * UOM rather than UOM.Value * UOM.Value would be best but its apparently not the most speed efficient).  All times in ms.

Multply doubles 7

Multply struct fields 8

Multply struct property 232

Multply temperature struct using overloaded * operator 141

Multply class fields 7

Multiply & Load doubles into object array 692

Multiply struct fields & Load into object array 719

Multiply struct fields & Load new struct into object array 926

Multiply structs with overloaded operator a load struct into object array 906

Multiply class fields & load into object array 697

Multiply class fields & load new class into object array 964

Multiply class using overloaded * operator & load class into object array 948

```
public class TestSpeed
{
    public class TempClass
    {
        public double value=100;
        private double v;

        public TempClass(double v)
        {
            this.v = v;
        }

        public static TempClass operator *(TempClass t1, TempClass t2)
        {
            return new TempClass(t1.value * t2.value);
        }
    }

    public struct TempStruct
    {
        public double value;

        public TempStruct(double v)
        {
            value = v;
        }

        public double GetTemp
        {
            get { return value; }
            set { this.value = value; }
        }

        public static TempStruct operator *(TempStruct t1, TempStruct t2)
        {
            return new TempStruct(t1.value * t2.value);
        }
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDouble()
    {
        double doubleValue = 100;
        TempStruct t = new TempStruct();
        TempStruct Tres= new TempStruct(100);
        TempClass tclass = new TempClass(100);
        double res;

        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            res = doubleValue*doubleValue;
        }

        watch.Stop();

        var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Debug.WriteLine("Multply doubles "+ elapsedMs.ToString());

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            Tres.value = t.value * t.value;
        }

        watch.Stop();


        elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Debug.WriteLine("Multply struct fields " + elapsedMs.ToString());

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            Tres.GetTemp = t.GetTemp * t.GetTemp;
        }

        watch.Stop();


        elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Debug.WriteLine("Multply struct property " + elapsedMs.ToString());


        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            Tres = t * t;
        }

        watch.Stop();

        elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Debug.WriteLine("Multply temperature struct using overloaded * operator " + elapsedMs.ToString());

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            res = tclass.value * tclass.value;
        }

        watch.Stop();
        elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Debug.WriteLine("Multply class fields " + elapsedMs.ToString());
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDoubleArray()
    {
        double doublevalue = 100;
        TempStruct t = new TempStruct();
        TempStruct Tres = new TempStruct(100);
        TempClass tclass = new TempClass(100);
        object[] res = new object[10000000];

        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            res[i] = doublevalue * doublevalue;
        }

        watch.Stop();

        var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Debug.WriteLine("Multiply & Load doubles into object array " + elapsedMs.ToString());

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            res[i] = t.value * t.value;
        }

        watch.Stop();


        elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Debug.WriteLine("Multiply struct fields & Load into object array " + elapsedMs.ToString());


        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            res[i] = new TempStruct(t.value * t.value);
        }

        watch.Stop();


        elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Debug.WriteLine("Multiply struct fields & Load new struct into object array " + elapsedMs.ToString());



        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            res[i] = t * t;
        }

        watch.Stop();

        elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Debug.WriteLine("Multiply structs with overloaded operator a load struct into object array " + elapsedMs.ToString());

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            res[i] = tclass.value * tclass.value;
        }

        watch.Stop();
        elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Debug.WriteLine("Multiply class fields & load into object array " + elapsedMs.ToString());

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            res[i] = new TempClass(tclass.value * tclass.value);
        }

        watch.Stop();
        elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Debug.WriteLine("Multiply class fields & load new class into object array " + elapsedMs.ToString());

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            res[i] = tclass * tclass;
        }

        watch.Stop();
        elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Debug.WriteLine("Multiply class using overloaded * operator & load class into object array " + elapsedMs.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: SPeed advatnage compared to what? If that is pure variables, why would you even assume that there would be a speed advantage? Struts are not overclocking the CPU. Tehy are brutally faster in larger tests compared to classes - because tehy produce no garbage for the garbage collector.

Comment: I'm under the impression structs are considred better than classes for UOMs, but not seeing that in the tests below.  Classes are convenient with inheritance.  ok, i get the garbage collector issue, whats a larger test?, i ran it a million times.

Comment: Something that overloads the memory and forced garbage collector.

Comment: Ok, i'm wondering if i can live with that.  I have a lot of iterative calcs on big arrays but the classes wont neccesarily be being created and destroyed on every iteration.  Having to use UOM.Value instead of UOM just to speed it up irritates me though.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between struct and class is memory allocation. Using class, you have a very small overhead. So you wont be able to notice the performance overhead.

Then the point of using struct is not using reference. Hence you dont need to worry about the value is changed in 1 method may affect another method.

Comment: Im not seeing any performance overhead anyway and I guess an 'In' modifier would do the same job to prevent a method from changing the values?

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "in" modifier?

Comment: in parameter, prevents methods form modifying any values, kind of the opposit of an Out parameter, wher you have to modify a value

Comment: But if you have hundreds of methods, you dont want to duplicate "in" everywhere. And if you have tens of developers in your team, you are not sure everyone will remember to do that.

Comment: I don't want to duplicate UOM.Value everywhere either to speed it up.  But no choice it seems.

Comment: That's right. You dont want to speed it up by 1/100000 second and sacrify the code consistency and easy-maintainable. Glad that it clears your mind.

Comment: Didn't clear anything actually, the speed is important and its doing millions of calculations

Comment: Well, I didn't do the benchmark, but I guess with 1 million calculation, it cost you 1 second (CPU processing time) by using strut. How many calculation exactly are we talking about? 1000 billion calculation? If you are willing to spend thousands of hours of coding/fixing/testing to save few thousands seconds. Then I think it's your choice.

Comment: Also, it depends on your system. If you're building a stock trading system, then yes, 1 millisecond is important. If you're building a weather forecast, data is displayed late by few seconds doesnt really matter. And no users will realize that, or benefit from that.

Comment: Total processing time can be half an hour

Comment: Which means you have about 2 billion calculations. Let's say each time, a user opens a browser, type in your web app url, the browser sends a request to app server. How many calculations happen for 1 request?

Comment: It's not that kind of application.  These replies aren't really relevant to the problem.

Comment: I know, sorry for taking your time.

Comment: No problem, I appreciate your trying to help